# Finding a string that occurs after and before a specified string in a vector

Tags: java, string, vector

I have a vector of vectors(which is not having a specified length). In this I want to find a string to be searched as well as it's follow-ups and pre-ups.
I have tried this do far. mainstr is my vector converted to string.

```
  String mainstr = "[[data link control], [communication, []], [computer, [applications     of computer, number of computer]], [world wide web], [lesson, [covered in lesson]], [access to remote], [marketing and sale], [electronic fund transfer], [network, [network of network, wide area network, communication network, computer network, [area network, [local area network, metropolitan area network]]]]]";

String search = "communication network";

if (mainstr.contains(search)) {
            if (mainstr.charAt(mainstr.indexOf(search) + search.length()) == ']' && mainstr.charAt(mainstr.indexOf(search) - 2) == '[') {
                System.out.println("single term");
            } else {
                int indexSearch = str.indexOf(search) + search.length();
                String followers = str.substring(indexSearch, str.length());
                if (!followers.equals("")) {
                    System.out.println("No FOLLOWERS");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("followers = " + followers.substring(0, followers.indexOf("]")));
                }
                if (mainstr.charAt(mainstr.indexOf(search) - 4) == ']') {
                    System.out.println("No pre found");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("preups are present");
                    String preup = mainstr.split(search)[0].substring(0, mainstr.split(search)[0].length() - 1);
                    String finalPreup = preup.substring(preup.lastIndexOf("[") + 1, preup.lastIndexOf(","));
                    System.out.println("final : " + finalPreup);
                }
                System.out.println("found...");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
```

In this case output looks like this-

```
No FOLLOWERS
preups are present
final : network of network, wide area network
found...
```

I have converted this vector to string then I have performed search but I am getting correct output for some string and in this specified case I am not getting the desired output. I was interested in generalized code which will work for any of the string present in a vector.
Thanks in advance.

Updation::

Actually this my tree structure which i have put in vector of vector.

```
-data link control
-communication
-computer
    - applications of computer
    -number of computer
-world wide web
-lesson
    -covered in lesson
-access to remote
-marketing and sale
-electronic fund transfer
-network
    -network of network
    -wide area network
    -communication network
    -computer network
    -area network
           -local area network
           -metropolitan area network
```

So i want the search will be as per tree.
for e.g. if search=="wide area network" then its followers=No followers because it has no hirarchy below means no element inside it. and its Pre up=netwok because it is sub element of head node network.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `followers.isEmpty()` is preferred above `followers.equals("")`.

Comment: If you're not getting the desired output in this case, what is the desired output then?

Comment: Did you think of regexps?

Comment: Sorry for thie in complete information. Following is the desired output-

followers = network
No pre found

Comment: @Dukeling I have edited my original question. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your code doesn't output what you want because you need to find the second-last index of `[`, not the last one. And, once fix, I don't think your code will be able to jump across nodes with children. For this I'd recommend a while-loop with a bracket counter.

Below is my attempt. It's just a basic program - there is no bounds checking, etc., but it should give you some idea of what to do.

```
  String mainstr = "[[data link control], [communication, []], [computer, [applications     of computer, number of computer]], [world wide web], [lesson, [covered in lesson]], [access to remote], [marketing and sale], [electronic fund transfer], [network, [network of network, wide area network, communication network, computer network, [area network, [local area network, metropolitan area network]]]]]";
  String search = "communication network";
  int start = mainstr.indexOf(search);
  if (start != -1)
  {
     int end = start + search.length();
     int count = 0;
     int pos = end;
     if (mainstr.charAt(end+2) == '[')
     {
        while (count != -1)
           if (mainstr.charAt(++pos) == ']')
              count--;
           else if (mainstr.charAt(++pos) == '[')
              count++;
        System.out.println("Ancestors = " + mainstr.substring(end+2, pos-1));
     }
     count = 0;
     pos = start;
     int lastComma = -1;
     while (count != 2)
        switch (mainstr.charAt(--pos))
        {
           case ']': count--; break;
           case '[': count++; break;
           case ',': lastComma = pos;
        }
     System.out.println("Parent = " + mainstr.substring(pos+1, lastComma));
  }
```

It is a bit of a problem when you're looking for a node that is the substring of another node that appears earlier in the string.

For this I thought regular expressions might work nicely:

Replace

```
int start = mainstr.indexOf(search);
if (start != -1)
{
```

with

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^|, |\\[)(" + search + ")(?:]|, |$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(mainstr);
if (m.find())
{
   int start = m.start(1);
```

[Test](https://ideone.com/Q4mi5F).

[Java regex reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: You have got what i want. Parent is coming right for all strings. But for some cases like for search="area network" it does not give ancestor. because its ancestors are "local area network" and "metropolitan area network". Thanks in advance.

Comment: After editing code given by you i got my desired output. Thanks a lot.